# Can't edit others' posts on Meta

Tags: support, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits, meta

I'm sorry if this isn't a bug and is just something I'm missing, but I've scoured the help section and can't find anything: is there a rep requirement for editing posts on Meta SO that's higher than on SO? I can edit posts on other metas, but for some reason, <kbd>edit</kbd> is grayed out here on every post:

[image: Menu: share, edit, flag]

I can edit my own posts (which I expected).

Comment: There is a tooltip when you hover over the `edit` button that explains that, so it's not a bug.

Comment: Interesting: I hovered over it before and didn't see that. The fact that it's not a bug is addressed in the answer below; the only reason I didn't delete it is because I didn't find any question or help section about it, so I've left it here for future users.

Comment: It's all good, just thought I'd mention it. :P

Comment: @TheQZ When I hover over the greyed-out edit in the image in AstroCB's post I see no tooltip.  Clearly it isn't working.  ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are no suggested edits for questions or answers on site metas.

To be able to edit a regular post you need full editing privileges on the main site, which is [2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

You can edit Community Wiki posts though - that only requires [100 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

Comment: I have reached 2000 reputation and can now edit Meta posts: [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: The 'Edit' Link on Main (SO) on Questions/Answers also has the Function to disclose/explain the (Markup) Syntax/Formatting used, pity it doesn't work on Meta for Users with <2k-Rep as mostly Advanced Users with High Rep and years of Exp on the Site post (Answers) on Meta, often using some "interesting"/useful Markup Syntax ... that remains "obscure" to <2k-Rep Users trying to answer some "small" Tags, ... and would like to use that "interesting" Formatting as well... (`<sub>` for example is not documented anywhere...)