# Why is the 'edit' button greyed out on this question?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596811/converting-string-to-ineteger), I noticed that the `edit` button is greyed out:

[image: Can't edit]

I noticed this on a few other questions, both on Meta, and the standard Stack Overflow.
I'm not currently banned from making suggested edits (at least, I shouldn't be; the majority of my edits are approved), nor am I banned from asking questions.

Why is the `edit` button greyed out?

Now it seems that I can edit the question:
[image: Can edit]

What's going on?

Comment: @derp I've been able to edit other questions before when an edit was pending, but however this question was one of my own (a user wanted to add 'Adobe Fireworks' to the title, although it was already tagged- so no need for the tag in the title [this was on SU)).
Is editing questions disabled when they have a suggested edit pending?

Comment: Rolled back the edit by the moderator, they edited it to remove the `Now it seems that I can edit the question:` and the following image.

Comment: @zyboxinternational I'm not a moderator and I didn't remove the image: I added alt text to it, which makes it look like I removed it and re-added it in the inline edit history: check the Markdown view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The button is grayed out because another suggested edit was pending for that post. If you are already editing the post when an edit is applied, you can *continue* to edit and submit the edit *as long as it is more extensive than the already-applied one*. However, you will not be able to *start* editing after one has already been submitted.

The button is grayed out on Meta because [you can't suggest edits to posts on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253538/cant-edit-others-posts-on-meta). You must have [full edit privileges](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (awarded at 2k reputation) to do so.

The general Stack Exchange-y way of explaining disabled features is via hover text: if you hover over a disabled button, for example, it will tell you why that button is disabled.

Seeing as there are no revisions in the post's edit history, the pending edit was rejected. Tomorrow, when the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](//data.stackexchange.com)'s data dump is updated, you will be able to [check that post's review history](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post?postid=16738968) to find the specific edit review.

The only other reason that the edit button would be grayed out is if [the post is locked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked-posts).