# Cannot edit others' posts?

Tags: bug, edits, privileges

Normally, when an error is seen, a user will go to the edit button under a post and help contribute by making a post more understandable, formatted correctly, etc. However, when I go to edit a post, the button is greyed out and I can't edit other's posts. Is this a problem with hidden privileges or a glitch? I used to be able to edit things just fine, but suddenly now I can't.
[image: Edit button greyed out]

**EDIT:**

Unlike [Why is the 'edit' button greyed out on this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270307/why-is-the-edit-button-greyed-out-on-this-question), which only happened on **some** questions, I am unable to edit **any**, posts, just my own. Additionally, nothing happens if I hover my mouse over the `edit` button, which some of you suggested.

Comment: @yellowantphil - nothing of the sort, nothing pops up. Additionally, it doesn't work for ANY post, not just one specific post.

Comment: @yellowantphil - Nope. Nothing pops up no matter how long I wait. It just shows a cursor and nothing else happens. Am I blocked or something else?

Comment: @yellowantphil - Ok. In inspect element it shows the title part, with the suggested edits and everything. Here is the full code: <span class="disabled-link" title="Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.">edit</span>

Comment: @yellowantphil - Thanks. One more question- do all the questions I can't edit really have a full queue or is that something else? Some others said they couldn't edit some posts, but it seems every single post i look for has a greyed out edit button. Is that another problem or just that i'm unlucky?

Comment: @yellowantphil - Ok. That's good then. No glitches. Thanks a lot!