# View instead of edit on Meta

Tags: feature-request, markdown

**Fact**
As discussed in [*Why are suggested edits not allowed Meta Stack Overflow?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262001/why-are-suggested-edits-not-allowed-meta-stack-overflow), you cannot edit Meta-SO posts [without 2000 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253540/3484570) on SO.

[image: No editing allowed]

**Problem**
I want/need to learn some markup like `<kbd>` and `<br>` or [that cool red button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271030/3484570) that I don't know how to do or snippets. Yes, there is the [editing-help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) but it is too long, complicated and incomplete. I tried finding the red button and failed. Snippets are nowhere in sight. So when I see something cool in someone else's post I want to click <kbd>edit</kbd> to see how it is done.

**Proposed solution**
Replace the grayed out <kbd>edit</kbd> with a working <kbd>view</kbd>. <kbd>view</kbd> should do the same as editing, except that there is no <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, no editing hints and no *reason for editing* field. Maybe the edit hints can be replaced by the explanation why editing on Meta is disallowed. This allows learning by example without touching the reason editing is disallowed, which is creating huge edit queues.

Comment: A lot of tricks and live markup is tried in [the formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Related on MSE: [View-source button when editing is unavailable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131513/view-source-button-when-editing-is-unavailable)

Comment: Past that, completely replacing the edit link with a view link when there's a suggested edit would just confuse more users. Not everyone who is explicitly looking for an edit link will notice that there's now a view link there instead - they're not looking for that word.

Comment: @animuson I thought about that too. Maybe it would be better to leave the edit link be and just add a view link.

Answer (score 32):

You can view the source for posts in their history view; take a look at [your question history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/271154/revisions) for example, there is a *source* link for each revision:

> [image: source link]

The Markdown source is then loaded and shown below the revision. If you are looking at a revision later than the first, make sure you are looking at the *inline* difference view to see the source too.

You can get to the history view for any post by using the URL:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/<postid>/revisions
```

If a post has been edited a *history* link is available, for posts without edits you'll have to manually enter the URL, or use a [user script that adds it in when missing](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a).

---

As for the red 'button', those are moderator-only tags:

```
[meta-tag:status-bydesign]
```

becomes [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). This only works for *actual, existing tags*. See [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259970#259970).

You can see this in the [revision history of the post you reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/271030/revisions); both in the side-by-side diff for the 3rd revision, as well as in the source you can load there.