# What's a secret hat?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2014

Christmas is coming and Stack Overflow is giving users "hats" as a reward when users achieve something. Like *Saint Lucia* for voting on December 15th, or *Handegg* for posting an answer to a question and getting a score of 7 or more.

But I've seen some secret hats like *Warm Welcome* or *Fascinating, Ma'am* with no hint how to receive them. So what's a "secret hat" and how can a user achieve those hats?

Comment: See: [Meta SE - Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats)

Comment: It's a.......... secret

Comment: Can we get a list of all the secret hats and how to obtain them once the Winter Bash is over ?

Comment: Hmm... It seems that the names of some of the hats might give clues for how to earn them. Martijn Pieters revealed how to get *Fascinating, Ma'am*, which makes sense as to why it would be named that... which makes me a bit suspicious about *Eureka*, for example... (or maybe they're just red herrings and I'm being misled.)

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Secret hats are hats that are not listed a-priori, and whose criteria are not disclosed.

The idea is that you discover for yourself how to earn them. Look upon them as [Easter Eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29)!

For example, to earn *Fascinating, Ma'am* you'd

> upvote an already highly upvoted question

It's more fun figuring out how to earn them for yourself however. Like solving a videogame without using a walk-through.

Comment: It would be nice though, if you were told how you got it once you get it. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol: there is a secret hat awarded to the first person guessing what the secret is about. That hat would be a little.. useless.

Comment: I got two secret hats by just login! Thanks SO :)

Comment: I want to know how you did the hover effect.

Comment: @mopo922: it's the spoiler tag; like a blockquote, but add an exclamation mark: `>!` at the start of lines.

Comment: @mopo922 Next time, just press "edit" beneath the answer to view the source.

Comment: Thx @Duncan but I don't have enough rep yet to edit.

Comment: @mopo922 You can suggest edits at any reputation level, so the [edit button](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/280286/edit) should always be available. If you click it, you can see the raw source of the answer.

Comment: @Duncan assuming you're talking about the "edit" link between "share" and "flag," it's grayed-out and clicking on it does nothing for me.

Comment: @Duncan: you cannot suggest edits on Meta, however. You'll need to look at the post history instead. Also see [View instead of edit on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271156)

Comment: @MartijnPieters How does the system, or the mods, know you are the first person to correctly guess what the secret is about?

Comment: @Luis: the decision to award Eureka is made entirely manually. A staff member makes the call; I guess they are tracking how public the info is and how correct someone's guess or deduction is.

Comment: I imagine that many of the secret hats are ones that are relatively easy to earn, but doing so intentionally would involve manipulating the "sincerity" of the database, like upvoting a certain number of comments or answers -- some people would start doing so just to get the (meaningless) hat instead of because the answers are actually worth upvoting.

Comment: *there is a secret hat awarded to the first person guessing what the secret is about* Wait, so we're *encouraged* to post our deductions? I've been avoiding doing so so as not to spoil. (Mind you, the only one I'm *certain* I've figured out is "Fascinating".)

Comment: @starsplusplus: people have been awarded the other hat by revealing their knowledge in chat too. But all hats are now described on Meta.SE already, so the staff member you are telling this to won't know if you found out for yourself or not. I am not sure any more Eurekas are being handed out now.

Comment: The fact that it doesn't tell you how you earned a secret hat once you've earned it just makes me say, "whatever" and go about my busy day not caring about hats.