# Greeter Hat seems to be causing problems

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

Is it just me or is the Greeter Hat causing a lot of questionable upvoting and trivial editing?

Perhaps I'm growing cynical, but it seems like I've come across a lot of polished turds with single upvotes this morning.

> **Greeter**
>   edit and upvote another user’s first post, which must have
>   been made during Winter Bash

[image]

While I understand the intent of this hat, it may be sending the wrong message to new users who've posted low quality questions.

Comment: That would seem like an extremely ill-conceived hat, as awesome as Winter Bash is otherwise

Comment: I suggest adding "I'm upvoting only for the hat, your post is not really good. Please improve it". Just kidding..

Comment: I think they try to motivate a gentle approach of new questions/answers... I think they are failing

Comment: BTW, trying to get the greeter hat without feeling guilty is proving to be a hurdle...

Comment: Maybe after this is all over they can take everyone who has the greeter hat and look for posts that have a negative score or are closed and suspend everyone who got it for voting fraud :-)

Comment: @psubsee2003: You mean suspend them for fraudulent hatting?

Comment: *"While I understand the intent of this hat, it may be sending the wrong message to new users who've posted low quality questions."* But it might send the right message to new users who have posted good quality questions with minor typos or poor question form, in that it shows the user how to properly format a question if done right.

Comment: @KevinB That would hopefully be the intent of the hat, but it doesn't seem like many hat chasers are getting that.

Comment: A much better indicator for being a good greeter would be editing plus having a comment on a first post with a score of at least 1.

Comment: I wondered if the person editing had to upvote, or of *someone else* had to, which would be a better algorithm...

Comment: @Pekka웃 that would make a little more sense, but there's a high potential for the hat to be awarded for snark and/or noise. As in: "I hate it when my `fuctions` don't work..."

Comment: @apaul the editing requirement should filter out most of those (even though it's easy to make a bad-faith edit, of course). Still better than the upvote requirement

Comment: @Pekka웃 Just thinking that the hat may end up being awarded for distinctly non-welcoming comments in some cases.

Comment: @Braiam Upvote first, _then_ edit (unlocking your vote). Wait until the hat is awarded, then reverse the vote.

Comment: After going through the First Post queue (and downvoting/flagging most) I finally came across one that was good enough to get an upvote. So I upvoted it... Stupid audit. Missed the hat :(

Comment: I see now why the awful made questions I've downvoted are upvoted immediatly, lol...

Comment: @psubsee2003 uhhhh.... luckily question for which I got it currently has 8 upvotes :)

Comment: @CaptJak that was what caused me to post the previous comment...

Comment: That's a bad hat, Harry.

Comment: Hatters gonna hat

Comment: I thought *I can find a good post no problem*. First one found was kinda bad, it only got worse :( The post I found was an answer; it read "For 500 (Server Error), you can post the error log first. Maybe let the others to clear it."

Comment: why oh [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)

Comment: Why is there no `Scrooge` hat? It should be awarded just for down voting your max allotted votes every day during Winter Bash and be the only hat you get to keep all year long! Oh wait, the quality of the site might improve considerably, silly me!

Comment: The only way to fix this to do what was intended is to change the criteria to **`Edit another user's first post, which never receives a down vote, close vote or flag afterwards!.`**.

Comment: @KevinB: From my experience, the whole edit low quality questions concept is a bit of a failure. Typos or slight grammatical errors generally fall under being too minor of an edit, while posts with problems more significant than that, are generally unsalvageable. The hat just exasperates the problem.

Comment: yes, that's certainly most often the case, making it hard to obtain this hat without submitting an edit that doesn't need to happen.

Comment: Sooooo... Are there any examples of bad edits that might have been perpetrated to score a hat? Or are we just guessing that the hat is the problem?

Comment: @JonEricson I would have to go digging for examples, mostly noticed the upvotes though. More or less a "Why would someone upvote this?", and noticed the edit after that.

Comment: @JonEricson I probably had a huge selection bias. I was looking for a half decent first post in the review queue, so that I could earn the hat myself.

Comment: This hat got me banned from reviews for the first time haha. I feel to greed and upvoted a first post without looking  :( :D Taught me a lesson!

Comment: There is no easy to get hat for those who just stumbled into this hat thing after Dec 14 and before Dec 18. I was tempted to try to get this hat even though it is plenty warm in here and hats just mess up my beautiful hair. There needs to be an actually easy hat and until there is, the easiest one will get abused.

Comment: I've actually notice recently nearly every post I was looking at had a single up-vote, and many times the question had a very poor quality.

Comment: @TonyAdams: There is one hat that is much easier to earn than Greeter. Not that I recommend it...

Comment: It does seem like this is becoming more of a problem.  The english language issue isn't so bad, as it can be fixed with some edits, though I understand that issue.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I came up with this hat. The original idea here was that we wanted to be helpful and welcoming to new users with edits. And since people aren't *supposed* to submit junk edits, the posts generally should be upvote-worthy after they've been edited, so that was made part of the trigger as well.

I understand that not all first posts will qualify. Sometimes an author will, for example, leave out critical information that a third party editor has no way of knowing. So, edit, comment, don't upvote, and try again for the hat on a different post. Other times, questions are just unsalvageable for a given site. Those should just be closed. (Hey, we even have hats for that too.)

Unfortunately, some people will always ignore the good behavior the <strike>badge</strike> hat was trying to encourage, and take the easiest possible way out. And that is why we can't have nice things. Seriously; at this point (not just because of this hat), I'm not entirely sold on holding Winter Bash again next year.

But to actually answer you: after the event ends, I'll see if I can somehow sift through the data to find out how the hat (and other hats) actually affected overall behavior and quality. I don't have a specific plan for how I'm going to do it yet, though.

Comment: Change the criteria to **`Edit another user's first post, which never receives a down vote, close vote or flag afterwards!.`**

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Does "never" mean that the user loses the hat if one is awarded? If we don't want to take away awarded hats, then perhaps the criteria could be refined to `Edit another user's first post, which does not receive a down vote, close vote or flag in the first X hours.` I suggest 12 hours, which seems like long enough for both SO and the lesser-known SE sites.

Comment: @Thunderforge - sounds reasonable to me to lose something if you did not do what the intended effect is, your suggestion will just cause people to edit and upvote in the middle of the night when the least amount of people are going to see it in `X` first hours. Anything short of a full circadian cycle would be exploited.

Comment: I would say it "where the post retains a positive score". People downvote for all sorts of silly reasons, I've personally seen my questions and answers with double-digit or higher scores get an occasional downvote for some indiscernible cause. However, as long as the question doesn't drop into negatives, there's obviously some value to it.

Comment: If it receives another down vote maybe it was most likely a poor choice and unsalvageable to begin with?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm more concerned with someone being awarded the hat on a genuinely good question (say, one that gets 10 upvotes because it is really a good question), then a week later someone spoils it by casting a single downvote for a bad reason (e.g. vindictive downvoting). I think that Chris Pratt's suggestion of "where the post retains a positive score" seems like a good compromise.

Comment: Either way it is unlikely that any change will be made.

Comment: Things are indeed pretty much locked in for this year. Good ideas for the future, though!

Comment: "people aren't supposed to submit junk edits, the posts generally should be upvote-worthy after they've been edited" BUAHAHAHA

Comment: I don't dislike the sentiment behind the hat at all, even though its current incarnation may be flawed. A "greeter" hat (or even badge!) could be an awesome thing if we could find a metric to define "Added a helpful comment to a first or early question". The best I can think of (as others have, too) is "a comment with one or more upvotes, and no flags"

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but SO has existed for quite a long time now (in Internet terms, at least), so you know how people react to gamification.  Why couldn't you anticipate the unintended consequences of this hat?

Comment: We always knew there would be _some_. It's a question of how much.

Comment: *"I'm not entirely sold on holding Winter Bash again..."* -- Noooo.. don't get swayed just because there are some who are finding the easy way to abandon good behaviour. Nothing is perfect. There will always be outliers, but that shouldn't mean we stop doing things that are fun! Just tweak the criteria here and there, and the world will be good again.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer) post on Meta StackExchange, some unmentioned rules like the ones you talked about exist.

Comment: oh come on - its a good hat! you cant blame the guy who offers you a special *.gif* for proactively supporting the distribution of information if you covet that *.gif* so well that you stoop to the distribution of *misinformation* in an effort to gain it. that problems ***all yours***.

Answer (score 17):

I agree, this hat is definitely problematic.  I think the *intent* behind the hat (more positive feedback to new contributors) is great, but in practice the hat all too easily just encourages robo-reviewing and mindless upvoting of bad questions.

Based on personal experience I'd even say that, even for people trying to review carefully and responsibly, the existence of the hat does create extra pressure to upvote new questions that perhaps don't *quite* deserve it after all.  In some cases this may be a good thing (as many people do tend to be excessively stingy with upvotes), but it can also lead to poorly written and essentially unanswerable questions getting upvoted and sticking around, when they really should've just stayed at score 0 until the roomba sweeps them away.

For this year, we're probably stuck with the hat as it is.  If a similar hat will be included in 2016, however, may I suggest changing the criteria to something like:

> Edit another user's first post, which then reaches a score of +2 (+3?).

and/or possibly (inspired by [Pekka's suggestion above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312313/greeter-hat-seems-to-be-causing-problems?cb=1#comment282827_312313)):

> Comment on another user's first post, with the comment receiving at least one (two?) upvote(s?) and no flags within 24 hours.

This would add an element of community feedback to the awarding criteria — not only do *you* need to upvote the question, but someone else also has to agree that the question (or your comment) deserves an upvote as well.  This should *hopefully* discourage people from trying to gain the hat just by editing and upvoting random unsalvageable questions.

Comment: "in practice the hat all too easily just encourages robo-reviewing and mindless upvoting of bad questions" 

So it "encourages" the norm?

Comment: Yup, it encourages it even more. That's bad.

Comment: I don't think the second suggestion would work, either. Some pretty negative comments can get heavily upvoted without actually being bad enough for a flag. I like the first.

Comment: Bad questions getting upvoted is a much much bigger problem than good questions that don't get an upvote with alacrity, IMO.  "as many people do tend to be excessively stingy with upvotes"  I see just the opposite "as many people do tend to be excessively **generous** with upvotes".  I suppose my cup is half empty.

Comment: @RobertCrovella and all our cups are tainted with Escherichia coli.

Answer (score 13):

Last year we had a similar hat: *Warm Welcome*. Unlike this year, it was [a secret](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280283/whats-a-secret-hat), which might be why it didn't cause any noticable problems. But the other difference is that it did not require an edit. Therefore it was impossible to detect the posts that people were voting on to obtain the hat. Even with full voting data, it's difficult to determine which votes were motivated by the hat and which were organic.

This year we can use internal data to estimate how many more people performed these actions in order to gain a hat. Specifically, we can look for people who vote and edit on first posts and compare that number to the rate last week or so. On the first day of Winter Bash 2015 (December 13), there were 407 Greeters awarded across all sites and 224 on Stack Overflow. Over the same time period a week earlier, there were 92 examples of Greeter behavior and 28 were on Stack Overflow. In other words, on SO the hat added roughly 200 extra "upvote and edit" actions.

Over the course of Winter Bash, the rate of extraneous actions should decrease as more people go from wanting the hat to owning it. We also can't easily tell which edits were frivolous and which votes were careless. Certainly I don't see any hard evidence that the hat did any damage at all. Maybe that could be added to your question at some point.

In "6-8 weeks" I'll take a look at the stats again. Because of the holidays, it probably makes more sense to look year-over-year rather than the previous period.

Comment: You could compare the eventual score of "greeted" questions after, say, 48 hours. (I could *almost* do that in SEDE, except that I can't tell if a user who edited a post also upvoted it.) If more bad questions are being edited and upvoted for the hat, that should translate to a lower average score for such questions.

Comment: Do you also have stats on how many people adds a comment to your posts compared to the previous weeks? :)