# Low quality/ off topic questions being up voted all the time

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, upvotes

Many times I see a reasonably new user at SO ask a really bad or off topic question (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300955/does-internet-speed-limit-the-amount-of-public-servers-you-can-have) one that prompted me to ask this question on meta).  That's understandable, but what I don't get is that pretty well straight away these types of questions get up-voted.

Is this a feature of SO to encourage new users by automatically up voting their questions, or am I stumbling into a conspiracy  of people deliberately up voting bad questions in order to game the system and get more rep?

Alternatively is there anyway to know who up-voted a question?

**Edit**

When I first saw it, it was definitely at 0.  The question in question then peaked at +1, but has now fallen to -1 and is heading to be closed pretty soon.

Comment: The meta effect has kicked in ;)

Comment: Very relevant if not duplicate: [Greeter Hat seems to be causing problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312313/greeter-hat-seems-to-be-causing-problems)

Comment: And no, voting is always anonymous to others, so there is no way to know for sure who voted on what.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: this actually predates the Winter Bash.

Comment: It's not necessarily a conspiracy; it's just other new SO users who have the same question(s), and don't know what's on topic either.

Comment: @Jongware sure, but the example given is definitely in the right time frame.  And I haven't noticed it very often on questions that aren't from days of different standards.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'd like to think that 2 people on SO didn't have the same ideas about a question like this!

Comment: @ryanyuyu Trying hard not to say `Well that's obvious` (about the Greeter Hat) in a sarcastic voice.  But yeah .. I can go with that.  However I see this sort of thing all the time and not just recently.

Answer (score 4):

People vote up for all sorts of reasons, many of which you may not agree with. They may genuinely think that the question is OK; they may think that they're helping new users by giving them a bit of rep (enough to comment etc.) - even though that's not how SO works.

All you need to do is vote as **you** see fit and move on to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the off-topic questions:

One thing I have noticed on this subject was that there have been plenty of questions I have Googled and ended up on SO for.  And while the questions themselves are alright and have usable answers for them, they are often labeled as "off-topic" because they do not necessarily belong on SO but usually one of the other SE sites.

Thus these new users are mistakenly asking their questions on SO and other new/passive users find their way to them via say Google.  Then, when the asked question matches their question and an answer on it provided them help, they up vote it, not even thinking or caring that it was more appropriate for the question to be on another SE site.