# Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

If I delete my answer, I can edit it deleted. But to edit my deleted question I must undelete it. Why this inconsistency?

Answer (score 20):

You cannot edit a **self-deleted** question, as this was open to abuse. To quote [Oded's explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#179555):

> With edit, it is now enabled on deleted questions, unless they are self deletes, as this can open a window to abuse (self delete, edit and later undelete immediately).

To prevent users from completely altering a question in the 'dark', a question needs to be undeleted for the author to edit it themselves. This way questions cannot be abused to work around question limits either; take an old deleted question, make it into a new question, undelete, in the hopes that it'll be received better, etc.

As deleted questions don't get shown in the active posts list, no-one could then review the edit.

If the question was deleted by anyone else, you can still edit it.

You can trivially bypass the restriction by viewing the revision history of the post (see [View instead of edit on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271154/view-instead-of-edit-on-meta/271156#271156) if the question was never edited before), copying the markdown source, then editing the post in a text editor elsewhere, then pasting in the new version the moment you undelete the post.

However, this then *does* bump the post to the top of the active questions list, hopefully drawing the needed attention to the question to review the changes made.

Comment: Why doesn't it apply for answers? (And btw, Oded, not Shog)

Comment: @nicael: because answers don't take the question with them when deleted, while a question when deleted takes a (single, not yet voted on) answer with it.

Comment: @nicael: but if people were to find a way to abuse self-deleting answers and use it regularly, it'll be disabled for answers too, I'm sure.

Comment: I can't see I really follow the difference wouldn't it still show in the revision history? BTW looks like that quote was from Oded.

Comment: @PeterJ: hehe, indeed; I got to that post by way of a [post from Shog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave) linking to it.

Comment: Why is this any different from undeleting then pasting in an updated version a nanosecond afterwards?

Comment: @MartinSmith: edit then undelete doesn't bump the question up to the top of the active posts list, while undelete then edit *does*.

Comment: Well the correct solution would be to make undeleting the question bump it then. Otherwise I could edit the question to something spammy, delete it, wait a week, undelete it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow, that's a rare known fact it seems. Should be made more prominent. Well, apparently I never needed to do so, hence I didn't notice.

Comment: Maybe this restriction could be lifted upon reaching a certaing reputation level? I just found myself in the situation that I posted a question by mistake while I was still writing it. I thought "ok, no problem, delete it, finish editing, and then undelete". But nope! :)