# Why can't I edit my own self-deleted question?

Tags: support, bug, edits, deleted-questions

I made a mistake when I asked a question, so I quickly deleted it, intending to edit it, then undelete it so it could be answered correctly. However, when I went to edit it, I found that I could not.

[image: a]

However, I feel like this is a bug. From the [Meta.SE question about deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/188673), it notes that:

> Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

Similarly, the [page in the help center about deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) says the exact same thing:

> Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

So then, why can't I edit my own deleted question?

Comment: @Kendra Hmm, yes, that does seem to be correct, though both the Meta.SE post and the help center need to be updated then. Perhaps this would be better-suited for Meta.SE instead of Meta.SO? Either way, I think that's a stupid policy, as [Martin Smith points out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281398/why-am-i-allowed-to-edit-my-deleted-answer-but-not-question#comment135348_281403).

Comment: Since the MSE post is a community wiki, I went ahead and edited it to be correct.

Comment: Editing a deleted answer is not a problem.  Surely the issue with editing a deleted question is that the many interactive checks on the post content cannot work.  Workaround is to copy/paste your old question.

Comment: @HansPassant It's really easy to work around, though. I ended up just editing my post in a text editor, then ninja-copying it into my post after undeleting it.

Comment: See [Couple of issues with Roomba Turbocharging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179555): *With edit, it is now enabled on deleted questions, unless they are self deletes, as this can open a window to abuse (self delete, edit and later undelete immediately).*. Yup, you can edit elsewhere, then ninja-paste after un-deleting, to work around that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If it's so easy to work around, why add the security-through-inconvenience that also removes a very valid use case? Was this really enough of a problem to warrant that change?

Comment: @AlexisKing: apparently. Oded nor any other dev has given a better explanation that I can find. Perhaps the typical user that'd abuse it is not creative enough to come up with that work-around.