# Can't view deleted question anymore, nor my comments on that question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, new-users, deleted-comments

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482470/how-to-loop-each-child-node-in-xls) was asked about 1 or 2 hours ago. He received a bunch of comments asking for more info, also from me.

Now [(s)he](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4477255/redhatkeps) deleted his question and asked again. Considering that this user only has 1 rep after 5 questions this year with only downvotes or none, he may be doing this more often.

Now, I don't mind someone deleting a question (though it is annoying to see it pop up again), but I have enough rep to view deleted questions. This question is really invisible:

- My comments on the deleted question do not show anymore
- Querying for [this user's deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/349442/deleted-questions-of-user-x) shows zero hits

I just wanted to check, without having to re-read his question again, what I wrote and if we can start answering him or whether I should copy/paste my original comments back in again. Or that I should just ignore this user, because he apparently doesn't like spending time on getting his questions right.

Comment: To my recollection, SEDE doesn't allow one to query for another person's deleted questions, so that query isn't very useful.

Comment: SEDE is only updated once a week anyway.

Comment: Do you still have history of the tabs you opened?  You can likely find the deleted post there.

Comment: @Makoto, good suggestion, and normally, yes, but I just cleaned out 70 of the 100 or so tabs, so even the closed tabs list doesn't have it anymore. I checked history, but there's simply too much. And what is SEDE? Is there a difference between a deleted Q. without answers and one with? Because I can see deleted Q's.

Comment: Abel, are you sure he's deleting and RE-posting, not deleting and undeleting? (I don't know much about what you see on deleted questions as a 10K user, so it might be a weird question to ask :p)

Comment: @Patrice, a deleted post keeps its comments, so undeleting a post keeps them too. Comments from me and one or two other users have disappeared. And as can be seen in edit history, _it is clearly not the same question_ (except for its content).

Comment: @Abel fair enough :) was just trying to see if something else might have been happening :P

Comment: I hadn't mentioned it before?  Sorry - it's short for Stack Exchange Data Explorer.  It's shorthand for the database you're querying against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deleting your own questions counts against the question ban:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/200235)

> #### Are deleted posts taken into account too?
>
> Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count towards an automatic ban.
>
> It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.
>
> Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts, including auto-deleted old low-score questions, all of which are only visible to moderators.

If you're correct about what this user is doing, eventually they will be automatically stopped by the question ban. I wouldn't worry about it.

Note that once you answer the user, they won't be able to delete the question anymore. So, let them do their own thing (and let them ban themself), or answer them if you're interesting in answering that question. I wouldn't concern yourself about it further.

It's also possible that the user is deleting and undeleting the same question over and over, which isn't exactly encouraged but is also fine, it doesn't harm anything. I'm sure if they do it enough it will trigger something in the system, but I can't speak to that. See: [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398/1768232)

---

As an aside, SEDE only updates once a week, so if you're looking for deleted questions by that user today, you won't be able to find any reference to them; only moderators have that power. [You also must search the `PostsWithDeleted` table, not the regular `Posts` table; that table has much less information.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/200235)

[Additionally, only moderators can search for deleted posts in the regular search engine.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134046/200235)

Comment: (downvote note mine) I wasn't aware of the automatic question ban. Do you mean that I can see his deleted posts (without an answer) after a week in his profile? Of would I see my comments back? Or none of the above and only for moderators (if no answer when deleted)?

Comment: I didn't see any other deleted post when querying, _if I'm right and allowed to query deleted posts_. It'd be handy to know. First offenders can be kindly directed such that they can become model citizens ;)

Comment: @Abel You can't see deleted questions in their profile. Being able to search for deleted questions on SEDE is a [fairly new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2678/revisions) and I'm not entirely sure how it works yet.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. (1) I can view other people's deleted and self-deleted questions [like this one w/o answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32419953), (2) I can query them, [this shows a list of recently deleted](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361211), (3) the query's most recent is Sept 6, three days ago, so I guess that's from the weekly cycle. Ergo, I can only view the deleted question if I accidentally still have the link or I have to wait a few days.

Comment: Mystery resolved, I found the [original deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479682/how-to-iterate-multiple-nodes-in-xsl-and-concatenate-the-results). **Conclusion:** deleted questions not yet processed for SEDE can be viewed (with deleted q. privilege) with a direct link, but not queried. After a while, they can also be queried.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this *again*, it's worth mentioning it to a moderator in a custom flag, as this sort of behavior may be indicative of attempting to circumvent various barriers and protections.

Outside of that, abandon the question.  For reasons only known to them, they elected to delete and recreate the question, and you're only here on your volunteer time.  I personally wouldn't want you to keep posting the same answer only to see it not appear.

If they keep doing that, it will likely fire off an automatic question ban for them.

Comment: I agree. In this case it was a discussion in the comments, not an answer yet (information missing/wrong/unclear, you know the drill ;). It just got me wondering.