# Suggest new tag accidentally submits question

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

A new question, I typed in the title, then went down to set the tags. I.e. the normal routine to see if there was a similar question that I'd missed.

The "golden-layout" tag hadn't been created, so I said yes to create it. Pressing enter to confirm the new tag submitted my question: even though I hadn't written the body, or had chance to look at similar questions yet!

(Unfortunately the body was a question from a previous day I'd chosen not to submit, so I then had a manic few minutes of trying to get the real question in there before it gets downvotes or flagged as gibberish!)

Comment: You can always delete, edit your question, and undelete when you're done.

Comment: There is no yes/no button to click when creating a tag.  To create a tag you just type out the tag; there is no button or prompt at all.  You clicked the "post your question" button which, unsurprisingly, posted your question.

Comment: @Servy There was a confirmation dialog. (Telling me to check spelling, be sure, etc. and then a do I want to go ahead.) Maybe it is new?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I actually did immediately delete, but then couldn't edit until I'd undeleted again. ("edit" was greyed out.)  Maybe edit-deleted-answers is a super-power I get later on?

Comment: @DarrenCook That sounds strange, I always could edit my deleted posts, no super-power needed.

Comment: Just did a test (and got my knuckles rapped - though it was only live for 2 seconds!) The greyed out edit button tells me it could not be loaded. I.e. it seems undelete is the only action I can do on a deleted post.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343657/testing-if-i-can-edit-after-delete  (if you can see deleted questions, of course)

Comment: Martijn Pieters just pointed me to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398/841830

Comment: "Please don't use Meta as a sandbox" would be a more appropriate knuckle-slap if there were actually a place that we *could* use as a sandbox. As it is, using Meta is far more appropriate than using main, and doing the test yourself and deleting it immediately seems preferable to wasting everyone's time with a question to which you expect an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I still regard it as a bug, but I'll change my future new question process to be:

1. Clear out any existing body text
2. Write the title
3. Add the tags (creating new tags if necessary)
4. Check similar questions
5. Write out body

Now if the new tag creation does try to submit the question, it will get caught on the "body empty" complaint.

Comment: If only adding the tags actually effected the search for similar questions... https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280668/178816