# What to do after accidentally submitting partial question

Tags: discussion, questions

I was composing my question but I accidentally <kbd>Tabbed</kbd> to "Post Your Question" and pressed <kbd>Space</kbd>.

I went to edit my question to write the rest of it, but by the time I was done someone already downvoted my question and voted to close it due to the details being unclear (as I was not done with writing the question yet).

I'd like to know what is the best course of action for this situation? Now my question has a negative score, and so people might be less inclined to put in some time to read it seriously. I considered posting another question with the same content but that is probably not the best thing to do.

Comment: I would copy all the information and delete it. Then paste it, finish it and make a new post.

Comment: @WELZ That's usually bad advice. The general guidance is to edit the question. You can delete it temporarily while drafting the full version but you should still use the same question :)

Comment: @Catija That sounds good, but the downvote came almost immediately after I accidentally posted the question. Kneejerk reactions and faith in humanity aside, I do believe that deleting and editing the question is not end-all.

Comment: well @peco, those user might think that you've posted your complete question and downvote it because it was a partial question? Just be double sure the next time you post.

Comment: @BhargavRao Definitely should double check, but the point is `accidentally`. I understand that users downvoted thinking I posted my complete question, but even after telling them in the comments they still didn't remove the downvote :)

Comment: They might have downvoted and left, something like *Eh, this is an incomplete question, downvote, and leave, no need to spend time on it*. You never know what can happen. Think of it like losing one limb in an accident  (Also, I'm bad at analogies)

Comment: @BhargavRao (modern medicine might reattach the limb if you get to the hospital quick enough!). Its more like people swiping left on Tinder because someone uploaded a bad picture. They're not likely to later swipe right when a better picture is available :)

Comment: @Gimby the modern medicine kinda fits my analogy. If peco was quick enough to update their post even before the downvoter closed their tab, then the downvote could've been reversed.

Comment: I do not want to start any flame wars, but would it be reasonable for a downvote to require a comment?

Comment: @lit No. It's been discussed over and over on MSE and it's not going to happen.

Comment: You can create new answer.

Comment: To avoid this happening, I usually add a tag I'm not allowed to use while I'm writing a question, and only remove it when I'm ready to post. The tags I'm not allowed to use are [untagged] or blacklisted tags such as [homework] on the main site, and moderator-only tags such as [status-completed] on Meta.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that actually sounds like quite an useful hack! Maybe a Chrome extension...

Comment: Aren't tags required for posts? Why don't you just not add a tag until you're ready to submit?

Comment: downvotes are generally countered when not retracted and not justified. I wouldn't bother about starting downvotes. People appreciate OP improving their posts. Also bumps the question at the top of the "active" page.

Comment: @WELZ That's why that comment should be an answer, so that it could be both upvoted and downvoted. Yes, people agree with you, but yes people also disagree with you.

Answer (score 16):

I've actually answered pretty much the same question over on Meta Stack Exchange:

[If you accidentally post a question before you mean to and it gets downvoted, what should you do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306379/284336)

I know that it can be difficult to overcome downvotes, particularly here on Stack Overflow, but it's really better for you to edit your question and hope that either the downvoter will retract the vote or someone else will upvote your question.

You can absolutely delete the question in the interim while you edit it - to prevent additional downvotes - but reposting essentially the same question looks like you're trying to escape the penalties of the downvotes - which you are, to an extent. If you do this multiple times, it looks really bad and someone will likely notice and flag your posts and you might even get in trouble with the moderators for it.

Note, you won't be able to submit the edit while the post is deleted but you can compose it in a text editor of your choice and then edit right after undeleting the question. In the future, it may even be better to draft your questions off site so that you can make sure they're complete before asking here. Undeleting doesn't bump your question, so it won't be immediately visible on the front page or in the active list until you actually edit it.

Comment: I don't know.. what if the OP just typed "My question is..." and then accidentally posted the question and received some downvotes. I don't think the people who downvoted would be interested enough to come back to see what the question was. It seems easier to me to delete the question and start a new one considering they posted on accident, instead of posting a bad question. If they post a bad question, then I do agree they should take the downvotes to heart and improve it. But if it's an accident, go ahead and delete it. Heck, you get badges for deleting a downvoted question.

Answer (score 6):

Next time this happens, you can immediately delete the question, finish writing the question, and then undelete the question, and edit the question with a paste of the updated content.

Comment: @Makyen You can't edit a self-deleted question without undeleting it first. See [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398/369450).

Comment: @cpburnz OK. I must admit I've only ever tried editing a self-deleted answer. Given that I have edited questions deleted by others, I had assumed (often a bad thing to do) that the user would be able to do so. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go against the grain here and say that it should be fine (in your case) to just delete your question and start a new one (just be careful next time). The situation you described—accidentally tabbing to the submit button and pressing space bar—sounds too uncommon to be a real problem. It's just a simple mistake. And in my opinion, since it attracted close votes, it's just going to get sent to the review queue in an unfinished state, and I think that is pointless and just wastes people's time.

On the other hand, if you simply posted a bad question and received downvotes, then I agree with the others and I think it is more fair to try to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for next time would be **formatting the question in a Markdown editor** and only pasting the final edit to the formatting box. This minimizes the risk of sending an unwanted question/answer.

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra work for every question to fix something that might happen once every few years.

Comment: @Goose not really that much more effort.  It is simply just an external editor instead of Stack Exchange's editor.  But there are lots of other advantages, such as multiple drafts, writing multiple questions in parallel while you do your research, saving questions that you want to ask in the future.  I don't do it myself much, but I see the advantages of doing so if i asked more questions or wrote more answers.

Comment: On the contrary, when I'm at the workplace and I have something minor I'm unclear about, what I really want to do is quickly send the question and get back to whatever I was working on before that. Context switches are expensive.

Comment: @the4kman Of course, the `horrible shame` stays with me. Which is why the last thing I want to happen to my question is to have it earn undeserved downvotes.