# Where to test Stack Exchange functionality

Tags: support

I wanted to see if deleted questions can be edited and then undeleted. I used meta.stackoverflow.com to test if this functionality existed. After deleting the question, I was told "This is not a testing sandbox, please don't use Meta for tests.".

Makes sense, but is there a testing sandbox?

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) does not allow me to test functionality related to questions, such as editing a deleted question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox ?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå that doesn't allow me to test what I mentioned int he question.

Comment: Why did you need to test if question deletion would allow you to edit? There are already questions about that functionality that would have given you an answer. There is no sandbox for question posting, but posting a question on Meta just to test *is still visible to a lot of people*.

Comment: See [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was trying to assist in answering this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364351/what-to-do-after-accidentally-submitting-partial-question?cb=1, I didn't find that question in my search, sorry about that. Just wondering here if there's an appropriate place to test something like this in the future or not.

Comment: I don't know of any options, but Meta and the main site are not really the place.