# Add a quick confirmation message when posting questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface

This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364351/what-to-do-after-accidentally-submitting-partial-question?cb=1) was recently asked. To summarize it, someone accidentally posted their question before writing their full question. As unlikely as it may sound at first, it isn't too hard to do if you really think about it.

All you need is a couple of tabs, a space key and boom - You've posted your incomplete question.

While this may not be a major issue, the fix isn't all that complex either.

What I'm proposing is a simple "confirm message".

E.X:

1. User Writes their question
2. User clicks "Post Your Question"
3. Dialog message that asks "Are you sure you want to Post Your Question?" appears.
4. User clicks "Yes", and the question is posted.

From a coding perspective, all you would need to do is...

1. Display a confirmation dialog box of some sort just before posting a question
2. If dialogue result is yes; then, continue posting the question
3. If the dialogue result is no; then, do nothing.

Whether the confirm message is a simple checkbox or a small dialog box. It does not really matter. It's just providing a second step to make it a little harder to post a question when you accidentally fly around the page with the ever-so-common tab key.

---

EDIT:
There was a comment about just immediately deleting your own question. 
There's 2 problems with this.

If your question has an answer with a up vote, you can't delete it. See this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) for more information.

If your question has a down vote... According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281398/why-am-i-allowed-to-edit-my-deleted-answer-but-not-question?noredirect=1&lq=1), you can't edit a self-deleted question. To make deleting the question work, you would have to delete and repost the question.
There is a problem with that method; however: You are by-passing down votes and can get in trouble with the mods.

Now, it's unlikely that an answer will get posted and upvoted before you could hit that delete button; however, it isn't all that unbelievable for a down vote to come flying by.

Also, some people might not be sure what to do and actually ask a/search for a question about the situation. In which case, there would be plenty of time for one of these 2 conditions to come into play.

Comment: There are other reasons this would be a good idea: [Establish a two-stage question commit process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289144)

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's an interesting reason; though, the feature requested would make the fix a lot more complex.

Comment: Can users not immediately delete their own question?

Comment: @MartinJames If memory serves, I believe they can if there are no answers with upvotes; however, with some quick searching I found a meta-question that is saying you can't edit a self-deleted question. Will update OP with this.