# Hide my own post to correct it later

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have written some misleading post, but solution to correct it took some time and effort. Only way to hide the post from public view is to delete it and later recreate. It would be nice to have a hide from public for later edits button, or a button before and after submit to make it public and thats it. This way you can write a post, edit it later when more suitable and then when your done with it, make it public. Each edit after publicity would be seen as edited.

Comment: Could you delete it, then undelete it?

Comment: If you're not done writing your post, and don't want it to be public yet, then *don't post it in the first place*, rather than trying to post it and have it not be public.

Comment: If only time travel were possible. "i *have* writtten..."

Comment: No wonder why this site has been stagnating - score has become the thriving force.

Comment: @Ako "No wonder why this site has been stagnating - score has become the thriving force." What? There's no indication that this site is "stagnating," and what do you mean by score being a thriving force? The people who have responded to you have just pointed out a better solution than your feature request.

Comment: Ako is probably reacting to the downvotes. @Ako, [voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I don't see why you all protect things which seen from usability standpoint are broken. Maybe I'm broken, but using a delete button to hide a post, external text editor to save post for later, etc what next will you come up.. Seen before how this community is lead by unknown dark force. Now I'm certain of it.

Comment: Related: [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398)

Comment: @KevinB They then switch to future tense half way through, and are asking for a feature to be added so that they can *plan* to do this in the future.  Hence my comment.

Comment: Nobody's saying the user experience can't improve; we're well aware of the deficiencies.  Ascribing hostility to what is a curation activity, though, misses the point of the activity.  If your post is not completely ready to withstand scrutiny, then...don't post until it is?  That seems to be a pretty reasonable compromise.

Comment: "_using a delete button to hide a post, external text editor to save post for later, etc what next will you come up_" Or you could just not post until it is ready. The suggestion is crazy because your premise is crazy. "_Why can't I post garbage and hide it?_" You can't because that makes no sense.

Comment: Seems like all this feature request can be achieved by changing the "delete" button to "hide" and "undelete" to "unhide" then call it a day it seems. I believe you can easily achieve this by some custom js browser add-ons.

Comment: QQ: what is functionally different between 'hide' and 'delete' here. Are we just splitting hairs? Cause it feels like we are. Delete does **exactly** what you want. You may find it silly to use that to hide something. I personally find it silly to have two buttons side by side in a UI when they provide no different function. If you can find a way to make the change more than just 'hidden' vs 'deleted' in the name... *Maybe* I could be convinced it's needed? For now... It's a waste of screen estate, since another button does it too

Answer (score 6):

While I realize that you may get new information about your question when you ask it, the *best* thing to do is to not post a question until you have **all of the information that you know at that time**.

Best thing to do would be to write it up in a text editor somewhere, go over it a few times to be sure it's complete and well-formulated, and *then* post it.  You can correct your question as many times as you like offline; you get a *handful* of chances to correct it once you have posted it.