# Can one edit a deleted post?

Tags: support, edits, deleted-questions, privileges

I posted a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387466/shall-we-have-badges-for-editing-posts-which-significantly-improve-them) (link is valid only to 10krep user) on meta yesterday but couple of hour later I deleted it - I was not sure my idea was described well and wanted to collect more data before re-posting.

However, I just noticed that **someone edited my deleted post**, as can be seen here:

[image]

How is it possible? Can other users still see my deleted post and react to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Users with over 10,000 reputation can see deleted answers and, if they have a link to them, deleted questions. And yes, deleted posts can be edited while deleted.

As far as 'reacting to it', I'm assuming you mean voting, in which case no, no one can vote up or down on deleted content. Users with 20,000 reputation or more can vote to undelete deleted answers (except when deleted by moderators), and users with 10,000 reputation or more can vote to undelete deleted questions.

Comment: Not relevant in this case, but note that [you cannot edit *your own questions*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mt5m.png) while they're deleted. This seem to be the only exception.

Comment: @JeremyBanks That's ...weird. Is that from your own test just now?

Comment: Yes, I just took that screenshot a few minutes ago. (I knew there was some case I'd run into before, but couldn't remember where it was, so I tested a few of my deleted posts to confirm.)

Comment: Here's the relevant meta post: [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281398/7795130)

Comment: @JeremyBanks Note that that only applies to *self-deleted* questions. If the community deletes the question, then the user doesn't have the option to undelete their own question and so that error does not appear and they can edit it.

Comment: One might still ask why Peter feels the need to bring his "Active Reading" (read: making an edit; yes we know that's what you're doing!) obsession to _deleted meta posts_ now too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit One might, but that's a subject for a different Meta question.