# Incorrectly tagged by a reviewer. After deleting, can I repost the question?

Tags: discussion

I posted the question *[How to enable the copy paste where it has been disabled using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69318785/how-to-enable-the-copy-paste)* which was actually tagged with [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension). However, a reviewer incorrectly removed this tag and instead tagged it [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), diluting it completely.

It appeared as a foolish question as to why I could not edit the web page myself.

I've deleted it. Will it be fine if I repost it?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't suffr the same fate. You've not posted any code showing what you're trying to do in your web extension. Doing that might also have made it clearer it was a web extension. Maybe also link to the web extensions documentation you're following too. Why not just edit it and then undelete it?

Comment: @RobertLongson probably because questions in a deleted state can't be edited by the OP...

Comment: @JonClements yes, if you've self deleted a question you have to undelete it first before editing it. You can always create the new text offline and paste it in immediately after undeleting if you're worried about getting downvotes/close votes before it's edited into shape.

Comment: All readers have read in incorrect context. Even if I undelete, nobody will come to read the stale content. I'd not get any solution

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry - I may have mis-read your "Why not just edit it and then undelete it?"

Comment: And you know that how? If you edit it, it will go to the top of the active questions list. There's lots of people look at that, I certainly do for questions I like to answer.

Comment: If so then I'll undelete it. Thanks for this info

Comment: @user5858 I think you'll have to suck up the -2 I'm afraid... you've got a fair few deleted questions (so don't want you to tip the automated Q ban) - maybe draft an edit and add a bit more info (although it's not my field - it does look like it could warrant a bit more info - try and bring the info from the link into your Q if you can somehow - external links are valid but sometimes frowned upon)

Comment: @philipxy I think that only applies to self-deleted Answers. See [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281398/why-am-i-allowed-to-edit-my-deleted-answer-but-not-question)

Answer (score 17):

Your question text is misleading (emphasis mine):

> **I've a** website and am not able to enable right click and copy text **using** a Chrome extension.

This makes it sound like the website is under your control and the Chrome extension is not. If your question is about how to *develop* a Chrome extension with the feature you want, so that it works on a website you don't control, your question should make both of those facts clear.

Don't rely on the tags to get across what your question is about - tags are only meant to make your question easier to find. If having the wrong tags changes the meaning of your question, then your question wasn't clear enough in the first place. According to [the relevant help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.

Addressing your meta question, there is no need to repost your question, just undelete and edit it.

Comment: I don't agree that tags are there only to help in search. I've seen, a tag gives strong indication of it's context. I do agree your first para though

Comment: @user5858 If a tag is necessary for context then that context should be provided in the question itself - otherwise desktop users will not see that context until they have finished reading the question. (Tags show above the question on mobile, though, for some reason.) I'll edit my answer to quote from the relevant help page.