# Misleading instructions for Closed question

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

[My Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75264791/2686187) was closed with the following message:

[image]

I chose the second option, "post a new one", and invested serious time and effort to improve the clarity of my question with more details. I deleted my former question, so it would not be regarded as a duplicate.  My improved question has since been answered and I marked the answer as a solution.  But now I'm being blocked from asking questions.

[image]

I'm told I must improve my questions before I'm allowed to ask questions again.  But I'm not allowed to edit my former question because I deleted it.  Going back to the blue screenshot above, "edit the question" was the only valid option, but, since I chose "post a new one", I have been unfairly trapped by the system.

Comment: You can undelete your old question since you deleted it yourself. About not being able to edit see: [Why am I allowed to edit my deleted answer but not question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281398/why-am-i-allowed-to-edit-my-deleted-answer-but-not-question) (Ah my bad I didn't notice "_My improved question has since been answered_" I thought you weren't able to ask the improved question, you probably shouldn't follow the advice to undelete in this case then)

Comment: I seems a bit silly to undelete it and add details and clarity because now it is a duplicate of the one I added.  I guess I shouldn't have deleted it but they never told me that.

Comment: Note that the "post a new one" means posting an *entirely* new one. If you deleted the old one because the "new" one would have been a duplicate otherwise, that means it wasn't actually new and you should have edited the old one. It's been brought up a few times that the wording is... misleading.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Quality control is important but can be frustrating on StackOverflow.

Comment: You're correct that it makes no sense to edit the previous question when you already posted another one, but this deleted question alone isn't the reason for your question ban. So you have other questions to improve.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400280/6296561

Comment: You're not alone in being mislead by that particular statement. Quite a few users have asked for that misleading text to be removed and these have always been historically declined.

Comment: Regarding "Please advise": Please see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/208273) (I'm reopening this one to focus on the misleading instructions for question-banned users)

Comment: "I deleted my former question so it would not be regarded as a duplicate." - You should have edited your question instead of deleting it and submitting a near identical question. The advice to "ask a new question", really means, ask a **different** question it does not mean resubmit the same question (even if you improve it). "But now I'm being blocked from asking questions." - You are question banned because, you ask questions, then deleted enough of those questions. **It appears your question banned is likely entirely due to the amount of questions you asked then deleted.**

Comment: @SecurityHound hold on, I was told that deleting a question simply doesn't prevent its low score from counting towards a Q-ban. Are we now saying that the deletion itself counts against the user? That seems **awful**. Users who recognize that a question is bad and not improvable **should be incentivized** to delete them, not punished.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the system is **awful**, though. To escape from the Q-ban, the system expects the user to un-delete the question **and improve it, even though** it is a duplicate. Worse yet, it might have been caused by a typo that was realized too slowly. If someone can ask the same question with much better quality by starting over, I say they should not be expected to overcome the downvotes the original version got (especially since *people who downvoted will rarely have any incentive nor motivation to come back and undo the downvote*).

Comment: Wait. Holy [yam](https://sopython.com/salad/). I just read in the FAQ there: "Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating (editing/reviewing) the question." So - if I see a question that I think is bad, but potentially salvageable with cooperation from the OP, **I am now disincentivized from editing to improve it** in case OP independently figures out the problem, deletes an acknowledged-still-bad question, and now I have indirectly contributed to a Q-ban for someone who acted reasonably.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Any questions that are asked are considered. I will just say that asking a question then deleting it, isn’t behavior, that is positive. If a question is closed due to it being a typo, the question, probably shouldn’t have been asked in the first place. Users who are question ban, rarely, act responsibly since a question ban is a result of their own actions and is a summation of their contributions

Comment: Security Hound & Karl knechtel I appreciate your discussion.  After my original question was closed, I deleted it in order to "post a new one".  That second version was also closed this time with a downvote so I deleted it in ordrer to "post a new one" which was answered and marked as a solution.   should have walked away at that point but I undeleted my deleted question and fixed them.  Now I got 3 more downvotes for posting duplicate questions.  Instead of **"post a new one"** it should say **"post a different question"**.

Comment: Tough balancing act, incentivizing askers recognizing and removing a weak or unanswerable question without also incentivizing bad deletion behaviour.

Comment: "*Instead of "post a new one" it should say "post a different question"*" [this has been pointed out to SE when they decided to change the close notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015) few years ago. So, [yes, you're right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/you-can-edit-the-question-or-post-a-new-one#comment807013_394578). However, as a community we've not had any power to change this.

Comment: I suspect the q-ban algorithm has a good memory because some of the downvoted questions (which were deleted) that likely contributied to my q-ban are from 9 years back.  Although to be fair I haven't added many questions since then.

Comment: It has an unfailing memory. Which is really unfortunate, since 9 years is quite a lot, to consider.

Comment: Unfailing and unforgiving. There have been several requests for weighting of posts to weaken over time or even vanish completely after a threshold because Joe Newb may have been a complete idiot at 13, but by 25 is s totally different person and could be a valued member of the community.